# Preposition for executing an action from a location

Tags: prépositions, indications-de-lieu

I'm having trouble figuring out how to say:

> It's not something I can give from thousands of km away.

The French preposition *de* is the only one I know that translates roughly as the English *from* in a locational sense, but I am used to there being a connotation of *origination* from as opposed to *action* from in the French *de*.

Would it be correct to translate the above as:

> Ce n'est pas quelque chose que je peux donner **de** milliers de kilomètres de là.

In more straightforward cases where distance is stated, the French *à* is used; so would it be more correct to say:

> Ce n'est pas quelque chose que je peux donner **à** milliers de kilomètres de là.

(I am obviously very much a beginner in French.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Depuis** (in this case = from) and **à** (in this case = to) would be valid preposition to talk about a location. However, if you want to stress the fact that you are not "geographically" present to give something, I would rather say (not a litteral translation):

```
Ce n'est pas quelque chose que je peux offrir en étant à des milliers de kilomètres de là.
```

Note that "donner" is usually an action that assumes some proximity (from hand to hand). In your case I would therefore suggest "offrir", but offrir is more specifically used for presents (so maybe not in your case).

Answer (score 2):

`from thousands of` is translated by `depuis des milliers de` where `depuis` is used to indicate the starting point in space.

Note that it can also be used to indicated the starting point in time. More details in [1]

The complete sentence would then be:

> Ce n'est pas quelque chose que je peux donner depuis des milliers de kilomètres de là.

[1] http://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/depuis/23940

Comment: Je préfère : Ce n'est pas quelque chose que je peux donner à des kilomètres d'ici. Le sens est différent, mais la référence à la position distante ne me semble pas naturelle.